# Get youtube old trending videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Working with YouTube Data API v3, to get the most popular videos i'm using:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=IN&maxResults=25&key=API_KEY
```

But i need old trending video **by a specific date**.

I tried `publishedBefore=2016-09-21` but it gives today trending videos.

**Update:** if this is not possible with YouTube Data API just a website/ database where i can find old youtube trending by date and country will do it for me.

**Update2:** using search not working because i don't need a keyword

Please Help

Answer (score 3):

Don't think `publishedBefore` works in videos.list. You are using [Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API call but this doesn't have a `publishedBefore` property. This filter only exist in [Search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list). However, I've noticed there's no mostPopular parameter in Search.list as well.

So, what I can suggest is use the order paramter with "rating" as value in Search.list.

Here's a sample URL call:

```
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=25&order=rating&publishedBefore=2016-01-01T00%253A00%253A00Z&q=dogs&type=video&fields=*&_h=8&
```

Comment: thank you, but i need the `mostPopular ` videos by date and country.. no keyword is needed

Comment: only shared what i think is available :) yours mifgt not be supported yet

Comment: OK Thank you noogui

Comment: @noogui would you please add some good tutorial over youtube's video list API. I have to get list of trending video list and then play. any tutorial to follow?